# setchildindex is creating problems

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have made a simple drag and match game for kids.

I used `setchildindex` for movie clips to be dragged but when I click next button and go to another frame but movie clips are remaining in the same stage. What should i do?

Here is my code I used: `(drag_1, this.numChildren0);`.

When I reload it's not working.

```
drag_1.buttonMode = true;    
drag_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropMe_1);    
drag_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragMe_1);     
var back_1X:Number = back_1.x;    
var back_1Y:Number = back_1.y;    
var hit_2X:Number = hit_2.x;    
var hit_2Y:Number = hit_2.y;    

function dragMe_1(event:MouseEvent)    
{
    drag_1.startDrag()    
    setChildIndex(drag_1, this.numChildren-1);    
}

function dropMe_1(event:MouseEvent)    
{
    drag_1.stopDrag();
    if(drag_1.hitTestObject(drop_2))
    {
        TweenMax.to(drag_1, 0.5, {
            x:hit_2X, 
            y:hit_2Y, 
            ease:Cubic.easeOut
        });
        drag_1.mouseEnabled = false;
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
    }
    else
    {
        TweenMax.to(drag_1, 0.5, 
        {
            x:back_1X,
            y:back_1Y, 
            ease:Bounce.easeOut
        });
     }
}
```

Comment: Do not understand your problem but setChildIndex(drag_1, this.numChildren-1); can be replaced by addChild(drag_1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `MovieClips` using `removeChild()`.

Now, why do you need to do that here? Well, this is one of those odd problems you get when you mix the timeline with code. When you place a symbol on the timeline keyframe, the Flash Player will instantiate that symbol when it reaches that frame. After that, any frame on the timeline that updates the symbol (tweens, effects, etc) will do just that, and any frame that lacks the symbol will remove it. However, the Flash Player is very picky about identifying that symbol on each frame of the timeline. When you move it using `setChildIndex` you are basically breaking the timeline link, and the Flash Player no longer identifies it and removes it based on the keyframes. You'll also find that if you revisit a keyframe that had that symbol, the Flash Player will instantiate a second one regardless if the one you moved is still there. As you can see, it can get pretty messy.

Comment: thanku so much it's working for my game now ...hope it will not create further problems